# React native firebase, getting data from a document based on a field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to get data from users documents witch contain the users profiles and i am implementing the edit profile screen, i have been able to get data based on the document id, but what i want is to get the document id using the (uid) inside the document to show the data based on the uid of the user, i tried to make the query but i couldn't use it right. 
if anyone can help .

and sorry i am new to firebase.

[image: the document from firebase]

and here is my code

```
       let db = firebase.firestore()


    var users = db.collection("users");
    var query = users.where("uid", "==", userID);


    db.collection("users").doc('4onJTLGXLlIvni7oQss1').onSnapshot((doc) => {


        this.setState({userInfo:doc.data() , loading:false})

        const {Fname,Lname,PhoneNumber,date,uid} = this.state.userInfo


        this.setState({
            Fname: Fname,
            Lname: Lname,
            PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber

        });
       // alert(userID)
    })

}
```